# Spring boot rest web application in netbeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans-8

I am trying to build first sample rest web application in spring boot using netbeans IDE.

I am getting an error 404 page not found below is my code.

Created class TransmissionController in package restservice

package restservice;

```
/**
 *
 * @author shubhgos
 */
import bean.TransmissionBean;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class TransmissionController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/TransmissionBean")
        public TransmissionBean greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
            System.out.println("name------->" + name);
            return new TransmissionBean(name, name, name, name, name);
        }
```

Created Bean(TransmissionBean) inside bean package

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package bean;

    /**
     *
     * @author shubhgos
     */
    public class TransmissionBean {

        private String fileName;
        private String date;
        private String fileSize;
        private String jobName;
        private String delivered;

        public TransmissionBean(String fileName, String date, String fileSize, String jobName, String delivered) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.date = date;
            this.fileSize = fileSize;
            this.jobName = jobName;
            this.delivered = delivered;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getFileSize() {
            return fileSize;
        }

        public void setFileSize(String fileSize) {
            this.fileSize = fileSize;
        }

        public String getJobName() {
            return jobName;
        }

        public void setJobName(String jobName) {
            this.jobName = jobName;
        }

        public String getDelivered() {
            return delivered;
        }

        public void setDelivered(String delivered) {
            this.delivered = delivered;
        }

            }

               }
```

Many times I tried to clean and build and run project but still I am getting error 404 not found.
Trying to hit below GET request

http://127.0.0.1:8076/toolWebApplication/TransmissionBean

Comment: Add the GET request you’re doing.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8076/toolWebApplication/TransmissionBean

Comment: Leave out toolWebApplication